# admin only can log from a certain country

Tags: users, security

I want that the admin user to only be able to log in from a certain country, and that the other users that are not administrators will be able to log in from every country.

Comment: this module may help you https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Smart IP module (https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip), you can add an extra validation on the login form that checks the country (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_validate/7).

You should check if the username exists on validation, when it exists you can check it's role and when it's the administrator role you make sure only users with the IP of your selected country can log in as admins.

There might be easier ways.